UnicodeDecodeError (utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x81) when using subprocess to run 'netsh wlan show profiles' command in Python
Hello, currently I'm trying to list Wi-Fi profiles on my Windows machine using Python's subprocess module. Here is my code:
import re
import subprocess

command = 'netsh wlan show profiles'
network_list = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True, encoding='utf-8')
networks = network_list.stdout

print(networks)

However, I'm encountering the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AGU\anaconda3\Lib\threading.py", line 1073, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\AGU\anaconda3\Lib\threading.py", line 1010, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AGU\anaconda3\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1599, in _readerthread
    buffer.append(fh.read())
                  ^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen codecs>", line 322, in decode
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 1673: invalid start byte
None

It appears that the output contains non-UTF-8(I think it is the '0x81' char) characters, causing the decoding to fail. How can I resolve this issue and correctly capture the output of the netsh wlan show profiles command?
I have tried it to decode in utf-16 (with adding "encoding='utf-8'" in the subprocess.run command but that didn't seemed to work[got another error]).

Determine what the correct encoding to use is, and specify that, instead of utf-8, to subprocess.run().  Possibly cp1252, but this can vary in Windows.

@JohnBollinger does 'mbcs' still work to select the native code page for your version of Windows?

@JohnBollinger actually now that I think about it, the cmd shell in Windows uses another code page entirely.  Mine is cp437.

FYI: 0x81 isn't supported in CP1252, but is in cp437(as ü).

What is the output when your command is run in the shell and which character causes the issue? Look for non-ASCII characters.  What does chcp report as the code page?

Also, with text=True, don't specify the encoding and Python will use the io.TextIOWrapper default, which should be locale-specific.

Although when tested on my system, a command like dir with cp437 characters (shell default) didn't display correctly.  It used CP1252 (Windows encoding, e.g. what Notepad would use) vs. CP437 (legacy OEM console encoding that the shell uses).  You can use text=False and receive the raw byte output instead, then .decode('cp437') (or whatever is correct for your system).
